# Special characters from a custom typeface not showing up in HTML

Tags: html, css, linux

I'm using the HP49 typefaces from hpcalc.org, specifically `FONT8.TTF`, for a small webpage.

The issue is, I cannot get the dark triangle to show properly. In the HTML, `&#x86;` it is displayed as "†" (with a fallback font), and the actual character is not displayed at all.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'F8';
    src: url('./FONT8.TTF')  format('truetype')
}
.SC {
    font-family: 'F8';
    background-color: #A8C0B0;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="column has-text-right">
    <p id="text" class="SC">
        &#x86;<!--non-printable character here-->{{ text }}
    </p>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <input type="" class="SC" v-model="text">
</div>
```

In the image link below, the right input box is linked to the left paragraph using Vue.
Manually typing the character using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then "86" **works fine**, but again, it doesn't work in the left paragraph, which is what I actually want. Also KFontView shows it properly.

In addition, doing `vm.text += "\u0086";` appends the character that I want in the input box but not in the paragraph.

Note: The `xxd` of the `.html` file shows the inserted character using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> in vscode as `c286`. Changing it as, e.g. `2086` doesn't work either.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1oqf.png)

Comment: Sounds right to me https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0086/index.htm

Comment: What table are you using that gives #x86 as a triangle?

Comment: The HP 49+/50 calculators have a 131x80 screen, so they use special characters and a limited number. The solid triangle (STO) indicates the saving of values in some variable. Using FontForge, I discover that the character I want is at 0xf086, and ` &#xf086` displays it correctly.
Footnote: Inserting into, e.g. LibreOffice Writer both 0x86 and 0xf086, both are displayed or mapped to the character in the table accordingly. I have no idea how.